# How to set fixed height to Viewport and enable browser scroll in GXT 2.x?

Tags: gxt

I want to create panel that fits window by width but has fixed height (using GXT 2.3.):

```
 public void onModuleLoad() { 
    Viewport viewport = new Viewport ();
    viewport.setEnableScroll(true);
    viewport.setLayout(new FitLayout());
    viewport.setAutoHeight(false);
    viewport.setHeight(700);

    ContentPanel cpanel = new ContentPanel();
    cpanel.setHeight(700);
    viewport.add(cpanel);

    RootPanel.get().add(viewport);
```

But when I resize browser window, viewport height allways recalculated.

So how to make it fixed?

Answer (score 0):

On solution would be to extend FitLayout to avoid to recompute the height on resize :

```
public class MyFitLayout extends FitLayout {

  protected void setItemSize(Component item, Size size) {
    if (item != null && item.isRendered()) {
      size.width -= getSideMargins(item);
      //size.height -= item.el().getMargins("tb");
      setSize(item, size.width, size.height);
    }
  }

}
```